# "UnknownError" when trying to GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to get messages as Admin (with Group.Read.All scope) I am getting following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "fc234750-dd35-4748-a1b3-baf4a7c5267c",
            "date": "2018-11-14T09:16:55"
        }
    }
}
```

Getting teams and channels works.

I tried the same using my user (not an admin, just regular user that created the conversation) in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and everything works ok.

Is this a bug or a feature (only user giving his permission explicitly allows the app to read conversations)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a member of the team? Admins don't get special privileges when working with messages – in order to read a message, they have to be a member of the team like anyone else.

Comment: Looks like so, but documentation does not mention that, and error itself is confusing :/